# Google Earth on Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, mobile-phones, google-earth

I have installed the Android Emulator:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

I now have it up and running using the eclipse plug in.

What I want to do is interface with/open/access google earth on the Emulated phone.. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must look at this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)